# How to return largest of two numbers from a callback function?

Tags: javascript, callback

So I'm supposed to write a function called 'sizer' using the arrow syntax that will return the larger of two numbers passed in using a callback function. I know the syntax for the arrow function just not exactly sure what I need to put for the parameters or what to put inside of it.

Arrow function :

```
var sizer = (callback) => {}
```

Callback:

```
sizer(300, 33, bigger => {
  console.log(`${bigger} is the larger number`);
  return bigger;
});
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, why a callback? It would be easier to just return the result of the test.

Comment: @Andy It's just how this specific challenge is for the assignment. We are supposed to be practicing with callbacks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this solution, I have declare a `sizer` function which takes two numbers and a callback function and return what the callback function returns. With one line arrow function the single statement result is returned. In the `sizer` I get the largest number via `Math.max` and pass it into the callback, then return it from a callback(this what you want).

```js
const sizer = (first, second, callback) => callback(Math.max(first, second));

const maxNumber = sizer(300, 33, bigger =>  {
    console.log(`${bigger} is the larger number`);
    return bigger;     
});

console.log(maxNumber);
```

Comment: This definitely works, I just think it's supposed to be a more simplified version since I'm just learning. We haven't even be taught the Math.max yet.

Comment: You mean understanable?

Comment: [`Math.max`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/max) is a pretty trivial function though. You could write `callback(b > a ? b : a)` , or `if(b > a) callback(b) else callback(a)`, but `Math.max` is a nice clean way to do it. It will also be easier to use if you need to take more than two numbers in the future.

Comment: Yes, I meant more understandable Suren.

Comment: It's also useful when trying to find the largest number in an array. Normally `Math.max` takes a series of numbers, but if you use `apply` you can feed it an array instead: `Math.max.apply(null, [1, 12, 2, 22, 5])` // 22.

Comment: I think the if statement is probably what they are looking for Karl. I get that Math.max is a cleaner way to write it. But I'm just not quite there yet.

Comment: Fair enough, as a beginner the if statement is probably the way to go. But if _you_ can understand `Math.max` yourself and can explain why you think it's better, you should use it. No teacher/instructor who's any good would mark you down for not giving the 'expected' answer in a case like this.

Comment: @Andy or, of course, just `Math.max(...[1, 12, 2, 22, 5])`

Comment: @SurenSrapyan thanks for adding the explanation. This is all really helpful!